# stem function error: stem required one positional argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk, porter-stemmer

here stem function shows error saying that stem required one positional argument in loop as in question?

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer as ps 

text='my name is pythonly and looking for a pythonian group to be formed by me iteratively'

words = word_tokenize(text)

for word in words:
    print(ps.stem(word))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to instantiate a PorterStemmer object

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer as ps
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

stemmer = ps()

text = 'my name is pythonly and looking for a pythonian group to be formed by me iteratively'
words = word_tokenize(text)
for t in words:
    print(t, stemmer.stem(t))
```

Comment: but why this shows an error if i use ps.stem(i) instead of stemmer=ps() and later run the 'print(ps.stem(i)'