# what is missing parameter in the below mentioned program?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk, porter-stemmer

For the below-mentioned python program it is displaying an error

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer 
ps=PorterStemmer
words = ["program", "programs", "programer", "programing", "programers"]
for w in words: 
    print(w, " : ", ps.stem(w))
```

> TypeError: stem() missing 1 required positional argument: 'word'

I'm not able to find out the missing parameter. What is that parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to instantiate the `PorterStemmer` class, not use it directly.

This:

`ps=PorterStemmer`

needs to become this:

`ps = PorterStemmer()`

More on the matter [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/stemming-nltk-tutorial/).

---

### Future word of advice

It is imperative that you try to research as much as possible before posting on stackoverflow. You could have found the answer to this question, as it is a simple question, if you took the error (exactly as it is) and just pasted it on Google.

You would have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54483061/nltk-portstemmer-missing-positional-argument) and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53140392/stem-function-error-stem-required-one-positional-argument) and many more. And you would have gained a lot more than simply getting the answer.